# Insert data into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a script with a database but it has been a really long time since I learned this stuff and it is keep giving me errors and it is probably easy for you guys =)

I want the input of this

```
<body>
<hr> bestelling <hr>

<form action="bestellingopslaan.php" method="post">

Bestelnummer <input name="bestelnummer" type="text"> <br>
Klantnaam <input name="klantnaam" type="text"> <br>
Artikel<input name="artikel" type="text"> <br>
Prijs <input name="prijs" type="text"> <br>
<input name="verzenden" type="submit" value="Verzenden" />

</form>
```

to this page

```
<body>
bestelling opslaan


<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '11092068';

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
Or die("couldn't connect to SQL Server on $dbhost");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbhandle)
Or die("couldn't open database $dbname");

//maak de query
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO bestelling ('$_POST[bestelnummer]', '$_POST[klantnummer]',     '$_POST[artikel]', '$_POST [prijs]' ) ";

if (mysql_query( $insert_query, $dbname))
{
    echo "de gegevens zijn opgeslagen in de database";
}
else
{
    echo "foutje";
}           
?>              
</body>
</body>
```

Here is a screenshot of my database

[image: database]

So, I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What errors, where and what you want to achieve?

Comment: First escape your user input and second name the columns: `insert into tab (col1, col2) values ('val1', 'val2')`. Google *Prepared Statements*

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and using a deprecated/obsolete DB library. Stop working on this code until you learn how to prevent the attacks, and then switch to a proper SUPPORTED library before you go any farther down this rabbit hole

Comment: I'm guessing there are some "undefined constant" errors (bestelnummer etc relating to `$_POST[bestelnummer]` < no apostrophes on the index), possibly some deprecated warnings about using `mysql` functions and someone really needs to invent a "Bobby Tables" Exception for all unsanitised database queries as this will fall right over that one.

Comment: @CD001 even if it had single quotes, the way he is using `$_POST`, it would still give you an error.

Comment: @job [start by posting the actual errors you get](http://www.phptherightway.com/#errors) and go from there.

Comment: @Prix not necessarily `$insert_query = "INSERT INTO bestelling VALUES ('{$_POST['bestelnummer']}',  ... ";` < that would work as long as $_POST['bestelnummer'] exists - it would still be horribly, horribly wrong, but it *would* work (granted, I had to add "VALUES" as the query, as is, would fall over I think).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You stand at getting a deprecation notice, and/or your query failed for some **unknown reason**, the error message you have not included in your question. You should catch the real error for your DB connection to get it instead of `die("couldn't open database $dbname")` - Use `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @CD001 yes but that is not just single quotes, you also added the brackets `{}` to define the variables which you haven't mentioned on your previous comment and without that it would still fail just with the single quotes. That is not horrible wrong but still allows for SQL injection.

Comment: @Prix - if I'd attempted to go through all the problems in detail I'd have hit the character limit in the comment long before I would have finished ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to see your errors, but from looking at your code It looks like you forgottten VALUES in your query.... It should be `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2 ,etc) VALUES`.....

- Consult: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Yes, the sql syntax error is part of the OP's problem. but don't like to w3fools. They're crap as a resource. Just because they show up first in google's results does NOT make them useful. Link to the actual mysql docs instead.

Comment: @ZiomekZiomski You don't necessarily need the columns name to insert data, his problem is the way he is using his variables within the double quotes and no brackets to define each variable or by concatenating it and probably others. Would have been simpler by using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: I agree with the comments given above. If anything, I suggest you find an `INSERT` example with code using `mysqli` or PDO with prepared statements based on what the OP is using. That would be a better answer.

Comment: It is fixed now :) I used MySQLI and that also took away a lot of errors. Thanks everyone (Y)